# dynamically style component containing third-party component depending on context angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, styles

Edit: the difficult thing here is that I can't change the class of the third party component. I need to add styles to the class `mat-form-field-wrapper` dynamically, which is part of a third-party (angular material) component

So let's say I have a component, "app-search-bar", which contains an angular-material "mat-form-field" that I want to style a particular way depending on where the search bar appears in my app. I know I can style third-party components using ::ng-deep and the !important flag but is there any way for me to apply such styles dynamically in different contexts?

What I'd like is a way to do something like this:

search-bar.component.ts:

```
    export class SearchBarComponent {
      @Input() styles;
```

search-bar.component.scss

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper {
      width: styles.width;
    }
```

Comment: you can refer similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437024/how-to-use-ng-deep-with-dynamic-data

Comment: that's a good idea but I need this same component to have different styles in different places and this approach would add those styles globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that i do i define a class for each scenario and take the class from input component. Example:

```
@Input() elClass = "my-default-class";
```

And then in the template

```
<child-component [class]="elClass">...
```

And in styles:

```
child-component.my-default-class ::ng-deep {}
child-component.another-class ::ng-deep {}
```

Comment: this is good but the thing I need to style is the third-party component within my component and not the component itself

Comment: @PeterWeeks You can add whatever you want to target after the ::ng-deep

Comment: ohhhhh I see what you're saying!! That's brilliant!! I'll try it out thanks! :)

Comment: edit: I'll just make a new question. Thanks for the help! 
ok, now what do i do if one of the places where I want to style it is inside a modal that gets added to the dom dynamcially? the css doesn't seem to be taking effect